# How to install gtest in OS X mountain lion

Tags: ros, macos, gtest, macos-lion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have been struggling to get ROS to install properly in OS X Mountain Lion. I am very close, but I need to install gtest. This i cannot get it to do automatically through brew because Google does not recommend installing a pre-compiled copy of gtest as per their wiki.

Can anyone guide me through how to install gtest from the source so i can get on with the ROS installation? Seems to be the only hickup I have left.

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46585/how-to-install-gtest-in-os-x-mountain-lion/) by [tropic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3186/tropic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 84 on 2012-10-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi tropic,

I had the same problem, check out this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/42335/mac-os-x-install-error-no-available-formula-for-gtest/

Hope it works for you.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tropic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3186/tropic/) on 2012-10-23**:
I actually tried that but it did not work for me :/
I get the following when I run rosdep install -a
No available formula for gtest (dependency of pcl)

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-10-23**:
Pay attention to the "UPDATE" on that question. Did you try adding the formula manually?

**Comment by [tropic](https://answers.ros.org/users/3186/tropic/) on 2012-10-23**:
Edit: I am sorry, I placed the .rb file in the wrong folder, I had it in Taps/ros-fuerte instead of Formula. I realized this when I was installing the newest PLC from http://pointclouds.org/ and followed their toturial.  It installed now. Thank you mate!

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2012-10-23**:
I am glad you managed to install it :)